# Why is my Erlang application crashing?

Tags: erlang, thrift, erlang-otp, rebar, erl

I'm building a simple erlang application and very new to the enviornment, so I'm having trouble making sense of some errors I'm getting. I'm not sure what the root of my problem is here, so if there's anything relevant that I don't post, please let me know:

Source for module I'm running:

```
  -module(basilisk_server).
  -author("Oak").

  -export([start_link/2,start/0,start/1,start/2, stop/1]).
  -behaviour(application).
  -record(options,{
    port = 6890,
    server_opts = []
  }).
  -define(LocalIP,"192.168.64.128").
  start()->
    start([]).
  start(Args)->
    #options{port = Port, server_opts = ServerOpts}  = parse_args(Args),
    spawn(
      fun() ->
        start_link(Port, ServerOpts),
        receive after infinity -> ok end
      end)
  .
  start(_StartType, Args) ->
    start(Args).

  parse_args(Args) -> parse_args(Args, #options{}).
  parse_args([], Opts) -> Opts;
  parse_args([Head | Rest], Opts) ->
    NewOpts =
      case catch list_to_integer(Head) of
        Port when is_integer(Port) ->
          Opts#options{port = Port};
        _Else ->
          case Head of
            "framed" ->
              Opts#options{server_opts = [{framed, true} | Opts#options.server_opts]};
            "" ->
              Opts;
            _Else ->
              erlang:error({bad_arg, Head})
          end
      end,
    parse_args(Rest, NewOpts)
  .
  stop(_State) ->
    ok.

  start_link(Port, ServerOpts) ->
    io:format("Starting server on port ~p with args: ~p~n",[Port,ServerOpts]),

    Services =
      [
        {"AuthenticationService",authenticationService_thrift},
        {"UserRegistrationService",userRegistrationService_thrift}
      ]
    ,
    {ok, _} = thrift_socket_server:start([
      {ip, ?LocalIP},

      {port, Port},
      {name, ?MODULE},
      {service, Services},
      {handler,[
        {"error_handler",  thrift_error_handler},
        {"AuthenticationService",authentication_service},
        {"UserRegistrationService",user_registration_service}
      ]},
      {socket_opts, [{recv_timeout, infinity}]}
    ]++
    ServerOpts).
```

I run `application:start(basilisk_server).` and get these messages in this order:

```
   {error,{bad_return,{{basilisk_server,start,[normal,[]]},
                      <0.38.0>}}}

  =INFO REPORT==== 29-Jul-2014::03:11:06 ===
      application: basilisk_server
      exited: {bad_return,{{basilisk_server,start,[normal,[]]},<0.38.0>}}
      type: temporary

  =ERROR REPORT==== 29-Jul-2014::03:11:06 ===
  Error in process <0.38.0> with exit value: {terminated,[{io,format,
 [<0.36.0>,"Starting server on port ~p with args: ~p~n",[6890,[]]],[]},
 {basilisk_server,start_link,2,[{file,"src/basilisk_server.erl"},{line,55}]}, 
 {basilisk_server,'-start/1-fun-0-',2,[{file,"src/basilisk_serve...
```

The main problem I'm having is identifying the actual source of the error. I was under the impression that `io:format` was the problem for a short while, but I believe that was a "red herring" and that bad_result is the root of my problem. I ran the program in an almost identical state and it was working, and suddenly started getting this error. I rolled back most of the changes and it hasn't stopped. I also tried rebooting, in case it was a problem with a background process.

Comment: Isn't this an ...interesting... length of time after a valid answer was given to downvote this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `application:start`, which expects your module to adhere to the `application` behaviour.

That is: it will call `foo:start/2`, to tell you that your application is starting. You are expected to return `{ok, Pid}`. This is documented in the "Applications" [chapter](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#callback_module) of the OTP Design Principles.

However, your `start` function immediately calls `spawn`, and uses the result of that. Since `spawn` returns `Pid`, rather than `{ok, Pid}`, `application:start` is complaining about a mismatch in the expected result.

Which is why you're seeing `bad_return`:

```
{error,{bad_return,{{basilisk_server,start,[normal,[]]},
                  <0.38.0>}}}
```

This is telling you that you got an `error`, of type `bad_return`. It happened when calling `basilisk_server:start(normal, [])`, and it got a return value of `<0.38.0>` (a pid).

Oh, and the other error is because you used `start_link`, which means that your two processes are linked. When one dies, the other will be killed. This is what you're seeing with the `terminated`. In this case, it happened to be killed in the middle of `io:format`; it might make it further before being killed in other runs.

Moreover, an application is assumed to start a root supervisor (this is what the returned pid is for).

At this point, you don't need the `application` behaviour. In fact, I'm not convinced that you need most of your code at all. Just call `thrift_socket_server:start` and be done with it. It'll continue to run in the background.

Comment: I was looking for the expected result of start but couldn't find it, thanks (I looked through the book I have here and it didn't make any mention of it, and I read that example but inferred "It is expected to return the pid of the top supervisor" to mean simply return a pid). Also I cut out most of the code for the example I posted, the behavior is doing more than it appears to here. Thanks for the clarification.